# When did K'Kruhk join the New Jedi Order?

Tags: star-wars

Wookieepedia says that K'kruhk rejoined Luke Skywalker's New Jedi Order, but he is absent from legacy books. When did he rejoin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_High_Council_%28New_Jedi_Order%29) on Jedi High Council says "K'Kruhk ω (—138 ABY—)"

However, that specific fact is **unsourced**.

His appearances on his own Wookieepedia page lists the first post-Vong appearance as ["Star Wars: Legacy 12: Ghosts, Part 2"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Legacy_12:_Ghosts,_Part_2), which is set in 137 ABY.

Comment: i guess that's fair enough